# Exponential Distribution - A question

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Would someone please give me a help with the problem below?

---

Suppose that the time between goals during the 90 minutes of regulation play in World Cup soccer matches can be modeled as an exponential distribution. The mean time between goals is estimated to be 33.7 min.

Suppose two independent World Cup soccer matches are being played simultaneously
(same kickoff time) and that you have been watching them live on television for the previous 15 minutes without a goal being scored. What is the probability that at least one goal will be scored (across the two matches) within the next 10 minutes?

---

$\lambda=\frac {1}{\bar X}=\frac {1}{33.7}$

So at least one means $1-P(0)$? But how to calculate $P(0)$ here where I got 2 matches?

Comment: Recall that the standard form for the Exponential Distribution is 
$P(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}, x \geq 0 $

Comment: Thanks. But how to apply the pdf in this case where I got 2x matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll offer two approaches. Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent Exponential random variables with $\lambda = 1/33.7$.

Define the events $A = \{X < 10\}$ and $B = \{Y < 10\}$. Then we need to find $P(A \cup B)$.
\begin{align*}
P(A \cup B) &= P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) \\
&= P(A) + P(B) - P(A)P(B) && \text{ by indepedence}
\end{align*}

The probability of these events can be determined using the CDF of an Exponential distribution. I'll leave that up to you.

There is a second approach, which is really the same as the first, but involves a different way of thinking (and generalizes to more games easily).

Let $M = \min(X, Y)$. Then we need to find $P(M < 10)$.

\begin{align*}
P(M < 10) &= 1- P(M \geq 10) \\
&= 1 - P(X \geq 10)P(Y \geq 10) \\
&= 1 - P(X \geq 10)^2 \\
&= 1 - (1 - F(10))^2
\end{align*}

Where $F$ is the CDF. These approaches yeild the same answer, but involve two slightly different ways of viewing the problem. The second approach using order statistics can be easily generalized to $n$ games, by replacing the squared term with an $n$.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! The second approach is fantastic!